# error handling when reading from buffer

Tags: network-programming, buffer

I have a tablet sending a 5 byte message to a device, the message i delivered ok but sometimes the data is written to the wrong part of the buffer.

the code i have for reading the buffer is as follows, buffer is an int[25]

```
if((tempByte != 0) && (tempByte != 0xEE))           // If 'ready' returned..
{
  tempByte &= 0x3F;
  if(tempByte > 0) 
  { 
    for(i = 0; i < tempByte; i++)
    {
      buffer[bufferWrite] =  periph_irxdata() ;
      bufferWrite++;
      bufferContents++;
      if(bufferWrite > 24) 
      {
        bufferWrite = 0;
      }           
    }
  }
}

if(bufferContents >= 5)
{
  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    readings[i] = buffer[bufferRead];
    bufferRead++;
    bufferContents--;
    if(bufferRead > 24) 
    {
      bufferRead = 0;
    }        
  }

  if(readings[0] == 0x18)
  {
    tabletValue = readings[2];
    OnOff = readings[1];
  }
}
```

The idea being that if you start at [0] and write 5 bytes each time a message of 18, 01, 02, 00, 00 would repeat starting at the values [0], [5], [10] [15] [20].

This would read 18, 01, 02, 00, 00 | 18, 01, 02, 00, 00 | 18, 01, 02, 00, 00 | 18, 01, 02, 00, 00 after 5 messages have been sent.

The problem is that occasionally an error occurs and the buffer ends up off bt one ot tow bytes and looks like this 02, 00, 00, 18, 01 | 02, 00, 00, 18, 01 | 02, 00, 00, 18, 01  02, 00, 00, 18, 01.

The messages are being sent find but the device ignores them as it see the messages as garbage as the do not line up with the reading blocks.

What can I do error handling wise to automatically fix this when it happens ?
I was thinking of moving the read to search for the next 18 and read 5 bytes or maybe try to find the next 18 and get the bytes written back into the correct blocks.

Comment: What protocol/interface are you using? Some kind of serial communication?

Comment: Is this C++, or something else?